# Enable category view when filtering community digests

Tags: feature-request, community-digests, site-categories

The [community digests](https://stackexchange.com/digests) page conveniently splits the various Stack Exchange sites to categories such as technology, culture, etc.:

[image]

It also has a handy filter option. However, when you use it, you lose the breakdown to categories:

[image]

I think it would be much more convenient to keep the breakdown to categories, and apply the filter to **each** category separately (and possibly hide categories that don't have any matches for the given filter).